# What is the dependence of an individual's religion when applying for an Indian visa?

Tags: india, visa, indian-constitutional-law

Recently a decision was made by those concerned in India to make the visa given to Afghan refuges to be independent of religion [(Source)](https://www.financialexpress.com/defence/india-introduces-a-new-e-visa-for-afghans-it-is-not-religion-based/2312231/). The article states that there is a religion based priority for giving visas, what ruling allows for this for in the Indian constitution?

Comment: **The article states that there is a religion based priority for giving visas** Where does it say that?  I can find religion mentioned three times in the link, all saying the opposite: *India introduces a new e-Visa for Afghans; it is not religion based* and *There is no religion based priority visa for the Afghan citizens* and *The most important thing is that the e-Visa is not religion based.*

Comment: @RockApe it could be an oblique reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship_(Amendment)_Act,_2019